# Secure a web resource by roles using keycloak

Tags: security, wildfly-10, keycloak

I'm currently checking keycloak example: servlet-authz. And learned that it secured a web resource via web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>All Resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
        <role-name>user_premium</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>
    <realm-name>servlet-authz</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-role>
    <role-name>user_premium</role-name>
</security-role>
```

My question is, can it be achieved dynamically? Without using web.xml? For example I have a new role role_guest, with only access to /guest/* url. How to configure that? I checked all the examples but none does so far.

Comment: Do you want to perform this check on the Java part using keycloak  Java client?

Comment: I would like to know both. But for now via keycloak should be fine.

Comment: I have the same question. I'm looking for a example or any reply without any luck.

Let me know if you found something please...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load all roles dynamically you have to include web.xml (unluckily) with wildcard (*) in both `auth-constraint` and `security-role`.

All roles allowed web.xml fragment:

```
...
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>
    <realm-name>servlet-authz</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
</security-role>
...
```

I don't know if there's a way to automatically attach to every role a `url-pattern`, which contains role name.

*Flow tested on Wildfly 11 with Keycloak adapter version 4.4.0.Final.*